# SwiftUI Custom TabBar View with nested NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uitabbarcontroller, swiftui-navigationview

Currently i'm Working in SwiftUi and I'm facing issue While using Custom TabBar With NavigationView issue like TabBar Not hiding when you navigate into a tab deeper! i have used like this

```
TabView {
    NavigationView{
        LeftView()
    }
    .tabItem {
        Label("Left", systemImage: "return.left")
    }
    
    NavigationView{
        RightView()
    }
    .tabItem {
        Label("Right", systemImage: "return.right")
    }
}
```

I want to hide Custom TabBar While i Navigate Deeper into some views in any Particular Tab

Comment: Add « .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)» modifier to LeftView and RightView

Answer (score 0):

```
    TabView {
            NavigationView {
                LeftView()
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Left", systemImage: "return.left")
            }
        
            NavigationView {
                RightView()
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("Right", systemImage: "return.right")
            }
    }
```